# Trig Substition: Why not use a $\csc(x)$ for $\sqrt{x^{2}-a^{2}}$ but only secant substition?.

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

Let Hypothesis = x,
Let $\cos(t) = \sqrt{x^{2}-a^{2}}$, $\sin(t) = \frac{a}{x}$

Then, for $y = \sqrt{x^{2} - a^{2}}$,
$x = a \csc(t)$
Then $\sqrt{x^2 - a^2} = \sqrt{a^2 \csc^2(t) - a^2} = a^2 \cot(t)$.

I don't understand why we only use $\sec{x}$ for $\sqrt{x^2 - a^2}$ situation

Any good insight will be great!!

Comment: Arbitrarily.  There are advantages to using $\sec$ over $\csc$ (for one, its derivative is free of negative signs).

Comment: Why is $\sqrt{x^2 - a^2}$ being multiplied by $x$ in the first line of the second paragraph?  Perhaps you need punctuation or words to indicate where one equation ends and another begins?